# Toma M900 Novacam I: My film winder does not advance film properly

Tags: film, repair, old-cameras, vintage

I just bought an old Toma M900 Novacam I ( *automatic point and shoot* ) at a dollar store.

Everything seems to be working find the first time I put batteries on it. However, when I tried to test the winder of the film after a camera shutter, it advances very slowly but when I put it on reverse, the winder gets really fast especially when I press the shutter.

Is it broken ? Is there any way I can use/fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed, the Toma uses an electronic motor to automatically wind the film. At this point, it's a very old electronic device with an unknown history bought at a non-camera store (the store has no incentive to service/repair it).

It could be used past it's prime and simply be wearing out (probable), it could have been dropped/damaged, it could have gotten wet, any lubricants that may have been used are definitely now past their prime.

So, the unfortunate reality is that this camera is cheaper to replace than to repair. (I found one that's brand new in the box on eBay today for $25, for example). So, I'd recommend simply replacing it. If you want to crack it to see if you can repair it yourself, you may as well. Don't be heartbroken if you destroy it in your attempt.